# Linking Facebook to ASP.NET application shows "Invalid API key specified"

Tags: facebook

I am trying to integrate Facebook into my application. When someone clicks the "Connect with Facebook" button in my app, a dialog appears that says "Invalid API key specified". Here is my code:

```
<fb:login-button onlogin='requestPermission();' length='long'></fb:login-button>

$(document).ready(function () {
    FB.init({
      appId  : '[MyAppID]',
      status : true,
      cookie : true,
      xfbml  : true
    });
});

function requestPermission() {
  FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("publish_stream", permissionGranted);
}
```

I have verified that '[MyAppID]' is in fact my application ID. When I log into https://developers.facebook.com/apps and look at my application, everything looks setup properly. Can somebody help me identify what I'm doing wrong or what I should be looking for?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog is really old stuff and may be deprecated soon, so you should use the newer Social Plugin for logging in

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

or you can use the Javascript SDK's login

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/